# What happends to a failed message in AWS SQS if there is no redrive policy set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I do understand that when I want my failed messages to be moved to a DLQ I can use a redrive policy, where I can mention the number of retries and the DLQ name.

What happens if I don't set a redrive policy? What is the default retry number and what happens when the number of retries exceeds the threshold?

Your responses are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQS messages only get removed from the queue if they've completed successfully - when a consumer grabs a message and then fails it becomes visible again the queue after a while.

In terms of maximum retries that depends on your retention period.

If you want to control this behavior setup a DLQ and set max retries to X number.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. So does that mean with no redrive policy (i.e. no DLQ setup), if I configure a AWS Lambda trigger from the queue and the Lambda function is not able to process & delete the message, then it will keep on going back into the queue and coming back to the lambda? Sorry if I my question sounds stupid!

Comment: Yes until the message expires.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: Is it possible to see when redrives happen (either in logs/metrics or as an cloudwatch event? )

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, I am curious if it will wait for the visibility timeout or not before adding to the queue back and retrying

Comment: I think I found the answer  from the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/working-with-messages.html#processing-messages-timely-manner)

> For example, if your application requires 10 seconds to process a message and you set the visibility timeout to 15 minutes, you must wait for a relatively long time to attempt to process the message again if the previous processing attempt fails.